# Is there any difference between LTRIM(RTRIM(MyColumn1)) and TRIM(MyColumn1)?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is there any difference between these two?

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(MyValue1))

TRIM(MyValue1)
```

I see a lot of examples that use LTRIM(RTRIM(MyValue1)), but my understanding is that this is equivalent to TRIM(MyValue1).

Am I missing something here (or was TRIM() introduced just recently which resulted in all of the examples that use LTRIM/RTRIM)?

Thank you in advance.

---

environment: SQL Server 2014 standard edition

Comment: THIS TOPIC APPLIES TO: SQL Server (starting with 2017) Azure SQL Database
Removes the space character char(32) or other specified characters from the start or end of a string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

TRIM() was introduced in SQL Server 2017.